# Java JTextField not updating text after setText()

Tags: java

I am trying to create a messaging application over LAN. Under `AppHost`, I am running concurrent threads for `HostUI` and `HostConnect` (one to display the UI and the other to receive/manage incoming and outgoing connections). I'm trying to write all these classes as singleton classes.

I'm trying to display the server IP address onto a `JTextField(ipField)` on `HostUI`, using `setText()`. After `setText()` however, the UI window doesn't display the updated text, despite the fact that `getText()` onto `ipField` WILL return the new text.

Here's code for the three classes:

AppHost:

```
public class AppHost {
    public static AppHost instance;

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[2];
    final int CONNECTION = 0;
    final int UI = 1;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads.length);

    public AppHost()
    {
        instance = this;
        //address = getHostIPAddress();
        threads[UI] = new Thread(new HostUI());
        threads[CONNECTION] = new Thread(new HostConnect());

        for (Thread t: threads) {
             executor.execute((Runnable) t);
             System.out.println("Running: "+t);
        }
    }
}
```

HostConnect:

```
public class HostConnect implements Runnable {
    public static HostConnect instance;
    private int port = 9000;
    InetAddress address; //Host Address. Server will be hosted here.
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket s;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    public HostConnect()
    {   
        instance = this;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Init Success.");
            address = getHostIPAddress();



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            s = server.accept();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

    }

    public InetAddress getHostIPAddress() 
    {
        try{
            InetAddress thisIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            return thisIP;
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
            return null;
        }

    }

    public InetAddress getAddress()
    {
        return address;

    }
}
```

HostUI:

```
public class HostUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    static HostUI instance;

    public HostUI() {
        initComponents();
        instance = this;
    }

    public void run() {
    new HostUI().setVisible(true);

    String addr = ""+HostConnect.instance.address;
    this.ipField.setText(addr);
    //System.out.println(ipField.getText());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When interacting with Swing components (getters or setters), you must be sure to call methods from the Event Dispatch Thread.

If not, use invokeLater :

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ipField.setText(addr);
        }
});
```